# Where can I find the "First Time here?" JavaScript component of the StackOverflow website?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, modal-dialog

I need to implement for my Grails web site something similar to the **orange and closable dialog that appears on the top of the StackOverflow website** whenever SO detects that it is your first visit. (for a demo, just start your browser in Private/Incognito mode and go to 
[www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com))

I am interested mainly in the front-end component.

Do you know where I can find a JavaScript/CSS/HTML library and/or code that will do the job?
Or maybe you do have the code source directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is really as simple as creating a CSS style for a div, something like this:

```
div.notification
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 1000;
    /* style it the way you want; background, font-weight etc. */
}
```

and then when you want to show a notification, you add a div with this class to the DOM. For example, with jQuery:

```
function displayNotification(text)
{
    var notification = $('<div></div>')
        .addClass('notification')
        .text(text)
        .click(function() { notification.remove(); });
    $('body').append(notification);
}

displayNotification('Hello World!');
```

Of course you can make it more advanced, but this is the basic idea.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple, they check if a "first_visit=false" type of cookie is set when you hit the page, and display that message if it's not.

This might be of help.. I responded to a similar question.
[Modal box + checkbox + cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604114/modal-box-checkbox-cookie/1604193#1604193)

Answer (score 1):

The UI paradigm is called a flash message or notifier.

http://rubypond.com/articles/2008/07/11/useful-flash-messages-in-rails/

StackOverflow uses the following markup and CSS:

```
<table id="notify-table">
  <tbody><tr style="" class="notify">
    <td class="notify">
      1 new answer has been posted - <a onclick="heartbeat.answers.update()">load new answers.</a>
    </td>
    <td class="notify-close">
      <a onclick="notify.close()" title="dismiss this notification">×</a>
    </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

#notify-table {
color:#735005;
font-weight:bold;
left:0;
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:100;
}
```

`notify.close()` would set `display: none;` on the notifier and, depending on your needs, set a `cookie` so that the message does not appear after it has been dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Or even easier with jquery:

```
$('div.notification').fadeIn();
```

with

```
    .notification { display:none;}
```

and

```
$('div.notification').fadeOut(function() { $(':parent .close').click(); });
```